# Can I edit a Label Frame that is not in the same function in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a program that upon clicking a button will allow the user to open a text file. Then, what is should do also is print the contents of the text file into a label frame which is in the parent window to the button. When I try to do this, I get an error: NameError: name 'LabelFrame' is not defined. Is it possible to edit a label Frame that is not in the same function?

EDIT: 
Here is a snippet of the code. The spacing may be a bit off, sorry.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def PerformTestScreen():
     performTestScreen = Toplevel(window)
     performTestScreen.geometry("400x225+10+560")
     performTestScreen.title("Perform Test")

     loadProg = Button(performTestScreen, text="Load Test", command=openPrevTest).grid(row = 0, column= 0, pady=10,padx=10, ipadx=30)

     paramFrame = LabelFrame(performTestScreen, text="Parameters",padx=15, pady=30)
     paramFrame.grid(row=1,column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
     test = Label(paramFrame, text = "this is a test label").grid(row=0, column=0)

def openPrevTest():
     fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("txt files", "*.txt"),("All Files", "*.*")))

     print(fileName)
     data = open(fileName).read()
     print(data) # prints contents of text file to terminal
     printParam = Label(performTestScreen.paramFrame, text=data)
     printParam.grid(row=2,column=0)

window=tk.Tk()

btn=Button(window, text="Perform Test", command = PerformTestScreen).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20, padx=20, ipadx=30)

window.title('Entry Screen')
window.geometry("400x160+10+10")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you share some relevent snippets? Thanks.

Comment: I can see a few problems here. 1st you have an indention issue in your functions. 5 spaces instead of 4. 2nd you reference `performTestScreen` as a function and a container. You are using the same name for 2 different things. This will cause problems.

Comment: I changed the names so they are not the same but I still get the same error @Mike-SMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct a few things here.

1. You have bad indention. I see 5 spaces instead of 4.
2. you have lines of code that belong inside your function but are outside of it. Maybe a mistake when moving your code to the question but as it is now it is a problem.
3. You need to pass the labelFrame to your 2nd function in order to work with it. You cannot simply call the toplevel window variable name outside of the function it was created unless you define it as a global variable.
4. Do not use both `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk`. I would say the best one is just to use `import tkinter as tk` as this helps prevent any methods being overwritten by mistake.
5. Lastly I rewrote some names and fixed spacing to follow PEP8 style guides for a cleaner code.

Here is your code cleaned up a bit with the needed corrections.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


def perform_test_screen():
    top = tk.Toplevel(window)
    top.geometry('400x225+10+560')
    top.title('Perform Test')
    param_frame = tk.LabelFrame(top, text='Parameters', padx=15, pady=30)
    param_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
    tk.Button(top, text='Load Test',
              command=lambda: open_prev_test(param_frame)).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=30)
    tk.Label(param_frame, text='this is a test label').grid(row=0, column=0)


def open_prev_test(param_frame):
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(('txt files', '*.txt'), ('All Files', '*.*')))
    print(file_name)
    data = open(file_name).read()
    print(data)  # prints contents of text file to terminal
    print_param = tk.Label(param_frame, text=data)
    print_param.grid(row=2, column=0)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Entry Screen')
window.geometry('400x160+10+10')
tk.Button(window, text='Perform Test', command=perform_test_screen).grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20, padx=20, ipadx=30)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just recently started coding in Python and I've been trying to figure this out for a bit. Thank again!

Comment: @sergio your welcome. Keep in mind that functions are self contained as in everything inside the function stays there unless otherwise specified.